# Data not inserting into table in Mysql/Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Dont know where the problem is.. but data is not showing up in the data base..

```
if(isset($_POST['sign up']))
{
$name=$_REQUEST['username'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$fname=$_REQUEST['fname'];
$lname=$_REQUEST['lname'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
mysql_query("insert into sign_up ('username','password','fname','lname','email')         VALUES('$name' , md5('$password') , '$fname' , '$lname','$email'");
}
```

Comment: This is the obligatory notice that you shouldn't be using the deprecated mysql_* functions. Instead mysqli_* or PDO is strongly recommended.

More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: this question is closed but simply you can add one ) small bracket at the end of your mysql_query before you have ended your query with double quotes ". Try it it will simply solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your column in the `INSERT` clause, they should **not** be wrap with single quotes as they are **identifiers** not string literals.

```
insert into sign_up (username,password,fname,lname,email) VALUES(...)
```

Since none of them are [**reserved keywords**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), backticks are optional around them.

- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_error() to get the error that is occurring. If this is all your code, it doesn't look like you're making a database connection first.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the single quotes around your database column names and it should work:

```
mysql_query("insert into sign_up (username, password, fname , lname , email) VALUES('$name' , md5('$password') , '$fname' , '$lname','$email'");
```

You also need to at least escape your data before inserting, and it is not safe to use `MD5()` for hashing passwords.

A really nice thing to read is here: It has covered a LOT with just little (enough) text - not only hashing:

http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer section is the wrong place for this but I can not seem to comment on your post, I think it might be because I am a new user...

Please read up on SQL injection before you put this on the internet.  You need to put protection into your inputs.